# Is there a faster way to clone limited mongo database

Tags: mongodb, export, clone

I want to clone remote Mongo Database to my local database with limited data. I know I can do it thanks to exporting each collection then import it to my local database. But is there any faster or efficient way that I can clone the mongo database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To take a database dump, you need to:

- connect to the server
- issue the query requesting the data you want
- receive query results (as bson)
- perform the minimum amount of transformations on that bson to get to the format you want to save in

mongodump with bson output and filter conditions should do these operations no less efficiently than any hand-built system you can come up with.

Same thing for importing.